# Assembly having problems printing after a divide (8086)

Tags: assembly, x86-16, divide

I am having trouble printing the value in al after I divide.  I keep getting a weird ascii character, not the 3 like im supposed to be getting.  If I put in a instuction mov al,5 it prints perfectly.  Any help will be appreciated.  Here is the code:

```
    mov ax,32511
    mov cx,10000

    div cx        ;divide 7eff by 2710.  Result in al will be 3. 

    add al,'0'    ;convert to ascii

    mov ah,2      ;print
    mov dl,al
    int 21h
```

Answer (score 1):

`div cx` is actually dividing `dx:ax` - you should zero `dx` beforehand for the result you expect.

To expand, it's performing: `(dx * 0x10000 + ax) / cx`, storing the quotient in `ax`, and the remainder in `dx`. If the quotient does not fit in `ax`, that is: `dx >= cx`, a divide (overflow) error is raised.

Comment: Tried that already, placing a mov dx,0 right before the print statement still produces the same problem

Comment: @user2858976, you need to put it before the `div` operation. Your bug is there, not the printing.

Answer (score 0):

`div cx` divides `dx:ax` by `cx`. So you should clear `dx` beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, it was my own stupidity.

didnt add this first

```
    mov       ax,@data            ; establish addressability
    mov       ds,ax               ; for the data segment
```